# Powershell Get-ChildItem appears to lock files for writing

Tags: powershell

I am executing a Powershell script to read the recursive contents of a parent directory and move files that match a pattern.

File are being written to the children directories by a separate tool that keeps them as ".filename" until the write is complete and then renames them to "filename" (without the leading dot).

The Powershell directory list command 'Get-ChildItem' appears to be locking files as they are being written, causing the tool to abandon the file write and resulting in many zero byte ".filename" files (the tool does not have a retry capability).

I say "appears" because when the Powershell script is running, the empty dot files show up. No script, no empty dot files.

The Get-ChildItem command is the only command in the script that touches these files. I know this command shouldn't be locking the files for write, but I can't find other possible causes. I am excluding .* when executing Get-ChildItem but I don't know what else to try.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Is there a command besides 'Get-ChildItem' I should be using?

Comment: This might likely have to do with how you have coded this. File might be open in the pipe while you are trying to move it. Breaking the code into two actions would fix that. Also if I am wrong we should still see code to get an exact idea of what you are doing.

Comment: I know if you say something like `Get-content $file | Foreach-Object { #stuff } | Set-Content $file` it will often fail due to it being locked. Without the code it's hard to say much more but my solution was to put the data into a variable, then pipe from that.